# check key path if it exists in nested dictionary

Tags: python

I have the following code

```
data = {
    "spam": {
        "egg": {
            "bacon": "Well..",
            "sausages": "Spam egg sausages and spam",
            "spam": "does not have much spam in it",
        }
    }
}

def does_nested_key_exists(dictionary, nested_key):
    exists = nested_key in dictionary
    if not exists:
        for key, value in dictionary.items():
            if isinstance(value, dict):
                exists = exists or does_nested_key_exists(value, nested_key)
    return exists
```

What I want is to check if key "bacon" exists. If it exists it should give the path as `spam.egg`. I am looking for the key path to iterate. I need to know what changes above code needs or how it can be done

Comment: So, where are you stuck?

Comment: It is giving true or false if the key exists or not. I need the key path where it us present

Comment: can you add an example when it's not giving you the result you expect?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want.

```
def does_nested_key_exists(dictionary, nested_key, keys=None):
    if keys is None:
        keys = []

    for key, value in dictionary.items():
        if key == nested_key:
            return True, '.'.join(keys)
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            keys.append(key)
            return does_nested_key_exists(value, nested_key, keys)
    return False, ""
```